# How to check if the input value contains the value of a given String in flutter?

Tags: android, regex, flutter

```
int X = 0123456789,
_areAlwdCharsTyped = false;
```

I want to check if the the value entered in a `TextFormField` by the user contains any of the values in variable `X`. It needs to happen real time as well.

As an example, if I enter `vV2g` in the `TextFormField`, it should show that `X` contains the value of `textEditingController.text`.

I tried to achieve this using regex. It works perfectly except for the part when I enter a number, delete it and then only enter some letters, `_areAlwdCharsTyped` still returns `false`.

```
int X = 0123456789,

if (myPsWrdController.text.isNotEmpty) 
{
 String allowedChar =
  X;
 final split = textEditingController.text.split('');
 split.forEach((c) {
  if (textEditingController.text.isNotEmpty &&
   allowedChar.contains(c)) {
    _areAlwdCharsTyped = true;
  } else if (textEditingController.text.isEmpty &&
   !allowedChar.contains(c)) {
    _areAlwdCharsTyped = false;
  } else {
    _areAlwdCharsTyped = false;
  }
  });
 } else {
   _areAlwdCharsTyped = false;
 }
```

How can I do achieve this using regex or in any other way? Thanks!

Comment: try to show your textField !

Comment: TextField is too long to copy and paste here with all the validations is has. But I have given all the values that are necessary for this question

Comment: As of your question what I understood is, you want to accept the input only when the input contains the characters in X (or predefined) ?

Comment: Yes, @NaveenAvidi

Answer (score 0):

```
RegExp reg = RegExp(r'^[cAzdTnJ574]*$');
//change the characters inside [] to your own !
  String error = '';
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                errorText: error,
                ),
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,),
              onChanged:(str){
                if(str.isEmpty){
                  state((){
                    error = '';
                  });
                }
                else if(!reg.hasMatch(str)){
                  state((){
                    error = 'Input invalid !';
                  });
                }else{
                  state((){
                    error = '';
                  });
                }
              }
              );
            }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I used `StatefulBuilder` to show real time error !

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is there a way to pass a variable into the [ ] to add the characters?

Comment: Yes ! You can directly assign value dynamically like reg = RegExp(r'^['+your_chars+']*$')

Comment: How u r trying !